How to draw box on the chart in pine script with absolute position. So the box is always at the same place
I'm looking to draw a box in Pine Script at the bottom of the chart and at the center of the chart. So the box will always stay at the same place. For this, I'm trying to get the bottom of the chart to keep always the same position.
So do you have an example how I can draw this box ?
And second option, I'm trying to also draw this box but at the right of the chart and verticaly centred. Ans the box will always stay at the same place, even if I move the candels on the chart.
I tried to use location.bottom for example but not sure I can use it for box. I see example on internet with plotshape but I need something like this to place my box always at the same place on the chart, relatively to the border of the chart and not relatively to the candels.
I tried already this but it seems that location.bottom can't be used with the box :
boxHeight = 50
boxWidth = 200

// Calculer les coordonnées de la box
//bottomY = location.bottom
//topY = int(bottomY) - boxHeight
leftX = bar_index - (boxWidth / 2)
rightX = bar_index + (boxWidth / 2)

// Dessiner la box uniquement sur la dernière bougie
if barstate.islast
    box.new(left=leftX, top=location.bottom , right=rightX, bottom=location.bottom,textcolor = color.white,border_width = 4,bgcolor = color.rgb(0,0,0),force_overlay = true) location.absolute

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Your code has "hallucinations".
AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...).
Consequently, TradingView and the PineCoders community have decided to not provide support to fix GPT-related code.

try table.new() with position.bottom_center
